# Need help/sugestion with Decision Trees in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, interpretation

**The Problem:**
I have a dataframe of 5 variables(all factors, the predictors have four levels each). Four of the variables are predictors and the variable I want to predict is a binary one. For some background, I want to see which variables are the ones that matter the most when we make ads to some companies.
I have 316 lines rows in that dataframe.

**My approach to solve the problem:**
So, knowing that I have to decide which are the most important variables, I tried to run a Decision Tree, so I would know exactly which variables are the most important and then I would know where to spend money with the ads.

```
set.seed(103)
data_randomized = Treino[sample(nrow(Treino)),]
training_size = round(nrow(data_randomized)*0.9,0)
validation_size = nrow(data_randomized)-training_size

training = data_randomized[1:training_size,]
validation = data_randomized[(training_size+1):nrow(data_randomized),]
```

90% of the data goes for the training set, while 10% goes for the validation one.

```
package(rattle)
package(rpart.plot)
package(RColorBrewer)
best_var <- rpart(training$onboarded ~., data = training, method = "class")
fancyRpartPlot(best_var)
```

This, alone, gives me some good trees. So, my doubts now!

**My Doubts:**

1. How do I know that the tree that I got is the best tree? Would I use AUC for it? Could you please explain how I do it with R?
2. Any other suggestions on how to solve the problem?